# If I can't login to my launcher and I can login to Minecraft.net and servers are on, what do I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I couldn't play Minecraft for 3 weeks and I still can't login. I know my password and E-mail is correct (I'm using a Mojang Account), But it can't connect to the servers. It says:

> I'm sorry, but we can't connect to our servers. Make sure that you are
>   online and that Minecraft is not blocked.

I've been searching the web for weeks, and I still can't figure it out. Minecraft isn't blocked, so how can I connect to the Minecraft servers or connect to be online?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't blocked? Your antivirus might be **block**ing it. (get the pun? you know, blocks in minecraft?)

Comment: Not sure if this is a true test.. But try going to command prompt/terminal and type "ping authserver.mojang.com"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, Minecraft is blocked by Windows Firewall. Go to Control Panel, and search "Windows Firewall" in the search bar. Click "allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall," and make sure Java is allowed.